# Angular 9 nested forms with template approach : how to add more than one of the same child component to the form object?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-bootstrap

I'm very new to Angular, but I tried a lot of googling to find a solution before I came here.
My problem:
With the template approach I try to create a nested form which inlcudes also the input fields of a child component. To get the child component registered in the parent form object, in the child component I added:

```
viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }
```

It works fine, and the child component inputs are now integrated into the parents form object. However, the child component is referred to more than once, so that its fieldset should be integrated into the formobject more than once. Instead the input fields of the child component are add only one time.I think this is because the inputfields need unique names otherwise they are just overwritte, or?
For more clarification, I use ngFor to loop over a configuration file which holds the information how often the child component needs to be loaded to the parents template. This is the template of the parent component where I loop over the configuration file. I create an accordeon with Angular Bootstrap:

**parent.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitJob()" #f="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div *ngFor="let process of processMappings">
        <div *ngIf="process.processId === selectedProcessingTool">
          <div *ngFor="let input of process.inputs; let i = index">
            <ngb-accordion
              #acc="ngbAccordion"
              activeIds="ngb-panel-0"
            >
              <ngb-panel title="{{ input.inputType }}">
                <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                  <child-component
                    *ngIf="
                      input.inputType == 'StaticSubsetDefinition';
                    "
                  ></child-component>
                </ng-template>
              </ngb-panel>
            </ngb-accordion>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the template of the child component, which includes a fieldset:

**child.html**

```
<fieldset ngModelGroup= "staticSubsetDefinition">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="value">Wert</label>
    <input
      style="max-width: 300px;"
      class="form-control"
      id="value"
      placeholder=""
      ngModel
      name = "value"
      required
    />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="dataType">Datentyp</label>
    <select
      class="form-control"
      id="dataType"
      style="max-width: 300px;"
      ngModel
      name="dataType"
      required
    >
      <option selected></option>
      <option value="text">Text</option>
      <option value="numeric">numerisch</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

The template of the parent creates an accorden with two panels, as the child is two times loaded to the template. However, the formobject does register only one, and I guess this is because the inputs need unique names.
My question therefore is, what can I do to change the name of the input field, e.g. by adding the index to the fieldset name?
I don't know how I can add the index to the inputnames of the child component e.g. in the for loop. How to do this? Or is there another way of telling Angular to add the form as often as loaded to the template?

I mean something like this between the stars (which is wrong, I know, just to give you an idea of what I mean):

```
<div *ngFor="let input of process.inputs; let i = index">
            <ngb-accordion
              #acc="ngbAccordion"
              activeIds="ngb-panel-0"
            >
              <ngb-panel title="{{ input.inputType }}">
                <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                  <child-component
                    *ngIf="
                      input.inputType == 'StaticSubsetDefinition';
                    " **inputname == 'inputname_ + i'**
                  ></child-component>
                </ng-template>
              </ngb-panel>
            </ngb-accordion>
          </div>
```

In essence, I don't know how to access the input field name from the template of the parent component. However if there is a total other way of adding the component fields to the forminput I would be glad how to do this within this code.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution by myself, and as I expected it was a simple solution, just by using Angulars Input directive:
I just need to add Input to the child component, define a variable which receives the values from the parent template, and use the values(here the index) to change the names of the fieldset in the child component with string interpolation :

**child.ts**

```
import { Input} from '@angular/core';
...
@Input() index: number;
```

In the child template I change the fieldsetname with string interpolation:

**child.html**

```
<fieldset ngModelGroup= "staticSubsetDefinition_{{index}}">
```

The values for the index variable then come from the parent template by using property binding `[index] = i`:

**parent.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let input of process.inputs; let i = index">
            <ngb-accordion
              [closeOthers]="true"
              #acc="ngbAccordion"
              activeIds="ngb-panel-0"
            >
              <ngb-panel title="{{ input.inputType }}">
                <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                  <child-component [index]="i"
                    *ngIf="
                      input.inputType == 'StaticSubsetDefinition';
                    "
                  ></child-component>
                </ng-template>
              </ngb-panel>
            </ngb-accordion>
          </div>
```